# Get correct SQL order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that selects trips by cities, and want to order by first those in City 1, then those in City 4. Many trips exist in 2 cities, so the database has 2 fields, StartCity & StartCity2. This SQL produces the wrong order:-

```
SELECT * FROM qryZZ WHERE (StartCity = 1 OR StartCity2 = 1 OR StartCity = 4
 OR StartCity2 = 4) Order By Case StartCity When 1 Then 1 When 4 Then 2 End
```

The results currently are:-

```
 Trip  |StartCity|StartCity2
 Trip1 |    3   |    4
 Trip2 |    3   |    4
 Trip3 |    1   |  NULL
 Trip4 |    1   |  NULL
 Trip5 |    4   |  NULL
 Trip6 |    4   |    3
```

What I want is first those trips with StartCity or StartCity2 = 1, then those with StartCity or StartCity2 = 4. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include both columns in the `order by` logic:

```
select *
from qryZZ
where StartCity in (1, 4) or StartCity2 in (1, 4)
order by (case when StartCity = 1 or StartCity2 = 1 then 1
               else 2
          end);
```

You might also want to separate out the two cities:

```
order by (case when StartCity = 1 then 1
               when StartCity2 = 1 then 2
               when StartCity = 4 then 3
               when StartCity2 = 4 then 4
               else 10  -- should never happen but put them at the end anyway
          end);
```

The strangeness in your results is because `NULL` values appear first in the `order by`.  Without a `where` clause, the sort value for "3" is `NULL`.

Comment: Great, that works, thanks! Just an add on, if I wanted to show the results from 3 cities in the city order 1, 4, 3 then I presume this is correct:-
case when StartCityID = 1 or StartCityID2 = 1 then 1 when StartCityID = 4 or StartCityID2 = 4 then 2 else 3 end.